# how to create custom field at frontend in wordpress?

Tags: php, post, wordpress

i want to create custom fields in frontend and also manage at frontend.

basically i want to create a slambook website where any user can create his slambook fields. and also manage as well.

i try a lots of plugins but nothing sufficient found.

> wp frontend user plugin

it give custom field for post but in backend.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Multi-post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97339/wordpress-frontend-create-custom-field

Comment: downvotes for what?????

Comment: exactly i want to know why you close this question??? @bwoebi

Answer (score 2):

The premiuim version of WP User Frontend does it

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/

But I am unterested in being able to create custom fields from front end using code. Anyone please advice us a tutorial on how to use backend functions in frontend?

Help appreciated.